# Google Heat Map: Uncaught TypeError: "Cannot read property 'alpha' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

**Description**

I am attempting to add multiple heatmap layers to a google map based on data returned from an api query. Everything appears to be working correctly however the error triggers after(not during) $ajax.done() is complete. I also noticed this error when I attempt to zoom after I added the layer. New Layer does not appear on map.

**Error Message**

*"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alpha' of undefined"*

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/OldCode101/jLK49/

**Code**

```
(function ($) {
var map, pointArray, heatmap, dataPoints = [],
    layers = [],
    $loader = $('.loader, .loader-overlay'),
    animation_speed = 666,
    $addLayerBtn = $('.btn.action-addLayer'),
    gradients = [{
        "0": "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
            "0.29": "rgba(148,0,0,1)",
            "0.33": "rgba(170,0,0,1)",
            "0.37": "rgba(191,0,0,1)",
            "0.42": "rgba(212,0,0,1)",
            "0.46": "rgba(233,0,0,1)",
            "0.50": "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
            "0.54": "rgba(255,21,21,1)",
            "0.58": "rgba(255,42,42,1)",
            "0.62": "rgba(255,63,63,1)",
            "0.67": "rgba(255,85,85,1)",
            "0.71": "rgba(255,106,106,1)",
            "0.75": "rgba(255,127,127,1)",
            "0.79": "rgba(255,148,148,1)",
            "0.83": "rgba(255,170,170,1)",
            "0.87": "rgba(255,191,191,1)",
            "0.92": "rgba(255,212,212,1)",
            "0.96": "rgba(255,233,233,1)",
            "1.00": "rgba(255,255,255,1)"
    }, {
        "0": "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
            "0.29": "rgba(0,0,148,1)",
            "0.33": "rgba(0,0,170,1)",
            "0.37": "rgba(0,0,191,1)",
            "0.42": "rgba(0,0,212,1)",
            "0.46": "rgba(0,0,233,1)",
            "0.50": "rgba(0,0,255,1)",
            "0.54": "rgba(21,21,255,1)",
            "0.58": "rgba(42,42,255,1)",
            "0.62": "rgba(63,63,255,1)",
            "0.67": "rgba(85,85,255,1)",
            "0.71": "rgba(106,106,255,1)",
            "0.75": "rgba(127,127,255,1)",
            "0.79": "rgba(148,148,255,1)",
            "0.83": "rgba(170,170,255,1)",
            "0.87": "rgba(191,191,255,1)",
            "0.92": "rgba(212,212,255,1)",
            "0.96": "rgba(233,233,255,1)",
            "1.00": "rgba(255,255,255,1)"
    }, {
        "0": "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
            "0.29": "rgba(0,148,148,1)",
            "0.33": "rgba(0,170,170,1)",
            "0.37": "rgba(0,191,191,1)",
            "0.42": "rgba(0,212,212,1)",
            "0.46": "rgba(0,233,233,1)",
            "0.50": "rgba(0,255,255,1)",
            "0.54": "rgba(21,255,255,1)",
            "0.58": "rgba(42,255,255,1)",
            "0.62": "rgba(63,255,255,1)",
            "0.67": "rgba(85,255,255,1)",
            "0.71": "rgba(106,255,255,1)",
            "0.75": "rgba(127,255,255,1)",
            "0.79": "rgba(148,255,255,1)",
            "0.83": "rgba(170,255,255,1)",
            "0.87": "rgba(191,255,255,1)",
            "0.92": "rgba(212,255,255,1)",
            "0.96": "rgba(233,255,255,1)",
            "1.00": "rgba(255,255,255,1)"
    }, {
        "0": "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
            "0.29": "rgba(0,148,148,1)",
            "0.33": "rgba(0,170,170,1)",
            "0.37": "rgba(0,191,191,1)",
            "0.42": "rgba(0,212,212,1)",
            "0.46": "rgba(0,233,233,1)",
            "0.50": "rgba(0,255,255,1)",
            "0.54": "rgba(21,255,255,1)",
            "0.58": "rgba(42,255,255,1)",
            "0.62": "rgba(63,255,255,1)",
            "0.67": "rgba(85,255,255,1)",
            "0.71": "rgba(106,255,255,1)",
            "0.75": "rgba(127,255,255,1)",
            "0.79": "rgba(148,255,255,1)",
            "0.83": "rgba(170,255,255,1)",
            "0.87": "rgba(191,255,255,1)",
            "0.92": "rgba(212,255,255,1)",
            "0.96": "rgba(233,255,255,1)",
            "1.00": "rgba(255,255,255,1)"
    }, {
        "0": "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
            "0.29": "rgba(0,148,148,1)",
            "0.33": "rgba(0,170,170,1)",
            "0.37": "rgba(0,191,191,1)",
            "0.42": "rgba(0,212,212,1)",
            "0.46": "rgba(0,233,233,1)",
            "0.50": "rgba(0,255,255,1)",
            "0.54": "rgba(21,255,255,1)",
            "0.58": "rgba(42,255,255,1)",
            "0.62": "rgba(63,255,255,1)",
            "0.67": "rgba(85,255,255,1)",
            "0.71": "rgba(106,255,255,1)",
            "0.75": "rgba(127,255,255,1)",
            "0.79": "rgba(148,255,255,1)",
            "0.83": "rgba(170,255,255,1)",
            "0.87": "rgba(191,255,255,1)",
            "0.92": "rgba(212,255,255,1)",
            "0.96": "rgba(233,255,255,1)",
            "1.00": "rgba(255,255,255,1)"
    }, {
        "0": "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
            "0.29": "rgba(0,148,148,1)",
            "0.33": "rgba(0,170,170,1)",
            "0.37": "rgba(0,191,191,1)",
            "0.42": "rgba(0,212,212,1)",
            "0.46": "rgba(0,233,233,1)",
            "0.50": "rgba(0,255,255,1)",
            "0.54": "rgba(21,255,255,1)",
            "0.58": "rgba(42,255,255,1)",
            "0.62": "rgba(63,255,255,1)",
            "0.67": "rgba(85,255,255,1)",
            "0.71": "rgba(106,255,255,1)",
            "0.75": "rgba(127,255,255,1)",
            "0.79": "rgba(148,255,255,1)",
            "0.83": "rgba(170,255,255,1)",
            "0.87": "rgba(191,255,255,1)",
            "0.92": "rgba(212,255,255,1)",
            "0.96": "rgba(233,255,255,1)",
            "1.00": "rgba(255,255,255,1)"
    }];

Array.prototype.clean = function (deleteValue) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == deleteValue) {
            this.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return this;
};


function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39, -95),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    $addLayerBtn = $('.btn.action-addLayer');

    $loader.fadeOut();
}

function addLayer(xxx, yyy, zzz, aaa, bbb) {
    var layerTextArray = [],
        $layers = $('ul.layers'),
        layerId = layers.length,
        $layer = $('<li />').addClass('layer').data('layerid', layerId);

    $loader.fadeIn(animation_speed);

    // ... do some stuff ...

    $.ajax({
        url: '/API/xxx',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            v: new Date().getTime(),
            xxx: xxx
        }
    }).done(function (response) { // returns JSON array of objects
        $(response).each(function () {
            var node = this;
            dataPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(node.latitude, node.longitude));
        });
        pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(dataPoints);
        var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            opacity: 0.8,
            radius: 20,
            data: pointArray,
            gradient: gradients[layerId],
            map: map
        });

        layers.push(heatmap);
        $loader.fadeOut(animation_speed);
    });
}

$addLayerBtn.on('click', function (event) {
    var $this = $(this)
        //...
        ;
    event.preventDefault();

    addLayer(xxx, yyy, zzz, aaa, bbb);
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);})(jQuery);
```

Comment: your fiddle gives a different error `Uncaught ReferenceError: xxx is not defined`

Comment: @geocodezip I have removed the sample code, try it again.